# docker-compose up and env variable

Tags: docker, .net-core

I use the following command

```
docker run --name mycontainer --env ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -d -p 5000:80 myimage:dev
```

and it works fine.

Now I introduced `docker-compose.yml` which has several services

```
version: "2"
services:
   myservice:    
    build: 
      context: ./MyService.Api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: myimage
    labels:
      - "com.microsoft.visualstudio.targetoperatingsystem=linux"
...
```

My question is:
when enter `docker-compose up` from the command prompt how can I provide `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` variable as I did in `docker run` previously?

Comment: You can use either the [`env-file`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file) or the [`environment`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment) feature of docker-compose files. See the links for specific examples and the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add an entry environment

```
version: "2"
services:
   myservice:    
    build: 
      context: ./MyService.Api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    image: myimage
    labels:
      - "com.microsoft.visualstudio.targetoperatingsystem=linux"
...
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment): You can either provide a list or a dictionary - should be `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development` or `-ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`.

Comment: thanks, but my questions was: how can I provide this env value from the cli command docker-compose up